# How to fix typescript issues using (@) Alisas in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having a little problem with using alias names with typescript. I am not sure how to fix it or what I am doing wrong. I have a React Native Project

When I try to import dataState into my ScreenA the following works without Typescript error:

```
import {dataState} from '@atoms/dataState';
```

However when I try to do the following typescript gives me error

```
import {dataState} from '@atoms';
```

> Error message: Cannot find module '@atoms' or its corresponding type declarations.

I can do the following without issue: I can remove the "@" and use relevant path and there is no issues

```
import {dataState} from 'src/atoms'
```

Project folder and file structure:

```
ProjectName
└── src
    ├── atoms
    │   ├── dataState.ts
    │   ├── currentFolderState.ts
    │   ├── editModeState.ts
    │   └── index.ts
    └── screens
        └── ScreenA.tsx
```

My src/atoms/index.js file

```
export {dataState} from './dataState.ts';
export {currentFolderState} from './CustomLayoutItems';
export {editModeState} from './editModeState.ts';
```

Below is my tsconf.json and .babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['.'],
        extensions: ['.ios.js', '.android.js', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
        alias: {
          // tests: ['./tests/'], // explained in the tsconfig.js
          '@atoms': './src/atoms',
          '@components': './src/components',
          '@context': './src/context',
          '@features': './src/features',
          '@screens': './src/screens',
          '@tabs': './src/tabs',
          '@hooks': './src/hooks',
          '@services': './src/services',
          '@utils': './src/utils',
          '@lib': './src/lib',
          '@types': './src/types',
          '@constants': './src/constants',
          '@navigation': './src/navigation',

          // Add the alias for path outside src directory
          '@config': './config',
        },
      },
    ],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      // Mirror this in the babel.config.js file
      // "tests": ["tests/*"], // Good example on including directory outside of src
      "@atoms/*": ["src/atoms/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@context/*": ["src/context/*"],
      "@features/*": ["src/features/*"],
      "@screens/*": ["src/screens/*"],
      "@tabs/*": ["src/tabs/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"],
      "@services/*": ["src/services/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["src/lib/*"],
      "@types/*": ["src/types/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
      "@navigation/*": ["src/navigation/*"],

      // Add the path outside src directory
      "@config/*": ["config/*"]
    }
  }
}
```